# My task is about PHP connectivity with xampp server which is not connecting and giving me erroe

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly show me the error in my code i am trying to connect the sign in form with database using php but i am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\php\signin.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\php\signin.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\php\signin.php:17 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\php\signin.php on line 17

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password="";
$dbname = "myproject";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO sign_in (username,password)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: what is not clear about `Access denied` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting this ERROR because of your is mixed up with mysqli_* functions and PDO code.

Methods of both PDO connection and mysqli_* are different.

Here is your error.
    ******Here is your error*****

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sign_in (username,password)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { //ERROR line
    echo "New record inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

You have use function `mysqli_query()` instead of accessing member function of `$conn`, just take below correct example.

```
// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Hope you get the point and will help you..

Comment: Or they could just replace `$conn = mysqli_connect(...)` with `$conn = new mysqli(...)`

Comment: *"You are getting this ERROR because of your is mixed up with mysqli_* functions and PDO code.

Methods of both PDO connection and mysqli_* are different."* - Huh? Where did *you* see a mix of apis? That should be stricken from the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There must be a password on root mysql account that you're not providing here:

```
$password="";
```

Other parts of the error is a direct consequence of this, $conn became a boolean and not an object as the mysqli_connect() is unsuccessful (it gives back false on failure).

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not correct, since no values where given to insert. It should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sign_in (username,password) VALUES ($username,$password)";
```

Comment: `VALUES ($username,$password)` - do you know what you wrote here? You do realize that those are not integers, but strings and need to be dealt with correctly.